# Segmentation of memory in the C language

Tags: c, memory

I am reading some text about the C language at the url https://cs.senecac.on.ca/~btp100/pages/content/compu.html. In the section "Segmentation", it says: 
"One logical technique for managing the addressing of a large number of bytes is segmentation.  Segmentation distinguishes certain regions of memory from other regions.  For example, an operating system stores program information in dedicated segments. "
[image]

I do not quite get it.

For example, if I have the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x = 4;
    int y = 5;
    printf("%d\n", x+y);
  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}
```

So, what is stored in Segment Code, what in Segment Data, and what in Stack? Please.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you sure you need to know this? Segments were important 25 years ago for 16-bit operating systems, but are totally irrelevant today.

Comment: 1+, not totally irrelevant but certainly not relevant in the same sense as for 16bit systems.

Comment: BTW, this is homework, right? Use the homework tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stack is your local variables (such as x and y). The code segment is for the binary code that is actually executed. Finally, the data segment is for values that your program uses (such as the PAUSE string there).

Comment: This is not technically correct in the sense of "standard C".  It might be true on some (or even most) platforms, but there is no requirement to even use a stack for the implementation.

Comment: @RandyHoward: You are correct but I made a judgment call on the depth of my answer based on the perceived depth of the question. I let voting and comments like yours either support or correct my general answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is compiler dependent. but in general, and assuming you have an OS that actually uses segmenation, your local variables `x` and `y` are referenced to SS, your string literals "%d\n" and "PAUSE" are referenced to DS and your actual assembled code is reference to CS.

Answer (score 0):

This question is system-specific. The segment descriptors are also used on 32bit Windows, for example, but for other purposes than traditionally in 16bit systems where one needed segmentation to refer to different areas of memory simultaneously.

32bit systems when using a 32bit wide pointer type can address the full virtual address space, which is why `fs` in Windows holds the key to special structures such as TEB and PEB. However, in the strict sense with a flat memory model there is no need for the segment registers.

Examples (Windows-specific, 32bit):

```
mov eax, dword ptr fs:[18h] ; pointer to TEB
mov eax, dword ptr fs:[30h] ; pointer to PEB
```

On many modern systems `cs` and `ds` will refer to the same area, for example.